# Angular $http promise not resolving

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I am currently working on building a login flow in AngularJS 1.3.  My problem is that the promise return from an $http call is not resolving the code inside of its '.then'.

I am working to handle error messages that come back from the server, specifically to handle any 401 errors which are returned when the user has input the wrong username or password.  However, when a 401 is returned, the .then never resolves itself and the code within them never runs.

The relevant code is as follows:

The controller for the login form as a login function on its scope, as follows:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    $scope.authError = null;

    // Try to login
    var promise = session.login($scope.user);

    promise.then(function(loggedIn) {

        // THIS CODE NEVER RUNS

        if ( !loggedIn ) {
            $scope.authError = localizedMessages.get('login.error.invalidCredentials');
        }

    }, function(x) {
        $scope.authError = localizedMessages.get('login.error.serverError', { exception: x });
    });
};
```

I have a session factory that takes care of the login and other session based needs.  The code for login is:

```
login: function(credentials) {
    var $http = $injector.get('$http');
    var url = ENV.apiEndpoint + "/sessions";

    var newSession = $http.post(url, credentials);

    return newSession.then(function(data) {
        session.set(data.token);

        //THIS CODE ONLY RUNS ON A SUCCESS RESPONSE

        if(session.isAuthenticated()) {
            closeLoginModal(true);
        }

        return session.isAuthenticated();
    });
}
```

I have placed comments in the code where the problem is. I am at a loss as to why this code isn't working.  From my understanding of promises, then 'then' should resolve no matter what the response was, success of error.

I have an interceptor running, but I have tried disabling it with no luck to the end result.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Wouldn't a 401 resolve to an `error` (or whatever it's called in Angular)? Does the error function run?

Comment: It does resolve an error, but if I am correct, a .then should resolve no matter whether the promise was a success or an error. The second function of the .then in the controller should be called if there is an error. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: ... So it's resolving, and running the error function. This would seem correct, since the HTTP call results in an HTTP error code. Maybe you're describing what happens incorrectly: is the error function being called?

Comment: It does get called, but the .then doesn't ever get run. Maybe I am misunderstanding promises.  I though that 'then' ran whether it was a success or an error...

Comment: You pass two functions into `then`. A success function, and a failure function. If you don't pass a failure function, it won't be run. The first function only runs on a success, and an HTTP error code of 400+ isn't a success. If your code is setting an HTTP code you need to take that into account. Try putting in the error handler in the login code.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried without success at first to pass a second function to the `then` without success until I turned off my interceptor I have running.  Now I am registering at least an error inside of the session promise.  This might be able to help me track down this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your login (server-side) returns an HTTP error code, like a 401, this should resolve to an error, e.g., the second function passed to `then`. If you don't pass one it should bomb out; that's why your higher-level error function gets called.

Comment: Thanks dave.  This has definitely been a big help.  I am not debugging the interceptor, but I am receiving the messages I need.